# Elements of postion absolute shifts on browser resize

Tags: html, css

When I re-size browser the elements whose position is set absolute does not changes according to other elements. if i place absolute divs inside relative then black box is not shown.

```
<div id="outer"></div>
<div id="blackbox"></div>
<div class="form"></div> 

#outer{
    width:1250px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}
#blackbox{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.form{
    width:500px;
    height:350px;
    z-index:20;
    background:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:100;
    left:400;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Used to this**

```
<div id="outer">
<div class="blackbox"></div>
<div class="form"></div> 

</div>
```

Define to **parent div**  `position relative` and **child div** `position absolute`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WfHc4/)**

**[More about Position](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)**

Comment: but when i do this only form is shown , it doesnot show that blackbox

Answer (score 1):

Absolute and relative positioning is relative to a "containing block"

Absolute blocks are placed relative to their "containing block". They define a new "containing block" for their children.

Relative blocks are placed relative to their in-flow position. They also define a new "containing block" for their children.

So, when you place an absolute block X inside a relative block Y you are saying "put Y in the flow of the page, shift it around a bit and then fix X relative to Y's new position".

Looking at the code - you have set `outer` to have a height of `auto` and `blackbox` to have a height of `100%`. So the parent's height is based on the child's height, and the child's height is based on the parent's height! So they collapse to 0px. That is why you are not seeing `blackbox`. [Try `#outer {height: 1250px;}` to see things...](http://jsfiddle.net/dr3daemon/4uhgz/)

Hope that helps, if not then read the specification - that is always the ultimate answer to all these questions (it's how I learned CSS)!

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your css. Change from `#blackbox` to `.blackbox`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="outer">
 <div class="blackbox"></div>
 <div class="form"></div> 
</div>

#blackbox -> wrong
```

use .blackbox {  }

Also remember that absolute positioned elements must always be inside relative positioned element

Comment: here, by mistake i wrote class="blackbox", in original code i have used id="blackbox", but the problem is that blackbox is not shown when i place it inside relative one